# what does it actually mean when they say "fragile state" in this context?

Tags: linux, operating-system

> Because signals are asynchronous, the main program may be in a very
>   **fragile state** when a signal is processed and thus while a signal
>   handler function executes. Therefore, you should avoid performing any
>   I/O operations or calling most library and system functions from
>   signal handlers

I want to do a test under this circumstance,but I don't know how to turn the main program into **fragile state**

reference: [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/025)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think "fragile state" is a technical term. I'm not intimately familiar with how the Linux lernel processes signals, but it's possible that the kernel disables (or lacks) certain safeguards while performing signal processing, such as thread safety on global objects or not expecting other side-effects.

For example, your quotation specifically mentions IO operations. An IO operation is typically asynchronous and causes an interrupt to be raised when it completes, I expect the kernel does not want an IO interrupt handler to be invoked while it is processing a signal (which I imagine would preempt the currently running code in the signal handler) and potentially put the system into an undefined state if the interrupt handler modified some resource that the signal handler was using, especially if the signal being handled was for a process that was also waiting on an IO operation.